# Breadcrumbs in account - necessary?

Tags: breadcrumbs

I absolutely understand the need for breadcrumbs and have found them to definitely improve e-comm performance, however I am struggling how much I need in account settings. As the only parents links would be account (dashboard) or home, which can easily be clicked from Nav. The only options is if you have separate breadcrumb link to edit page for adding info but most of that can be handles in pop-ups.

So I am curious to see if you guys feel breadcrumbs are necessary in account?

Comment: UI conventions tend to be based on real world metaphors. Breadcrumb trails are for trips through the woods, not going to the neighbors. If in accounts there are no lengthy paths or there's no benefit to the user to know how they got to where they are, then don't unnecessarily clutter the interface nor add to the development load.

Comment: If you want the breadcrumbs on the account page just for consistency. Instead of a link to the parent page, the breadcrumb item can also be a back link to the last visited product or page. Since this is different to other breadcrumbs it is important to show the difference, a clear label and a back arrow for example: `← back to product x`. I can't really answer the question though, because it depends on the context. The consistency can for example be helpful for less technical (elder) people who make mistakes and get disorientated more easily or forgot about the back button of their browser.

Answer (score 1):

Breadcrumbs generally help to support wayfinding by reflecting the information hierarchy of your site. It's not category dependent, but context dependent.

An account can have breadcrumbs if there are so many nested hierarchies you want to include, is it possible to see a screenshot to advise better?